# windows.location not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a novice when it comes to jquery/javascript, but I'm trying my best to figure this one out. If anyone has insight on this, I would greatly appreciate it.  I am trying to append a link to a filterable video gallery. I've tried the code below and it works fine when I'm on a desktop, but on a mobile device, the MORE VIDEOS link doesn't go to the specified URL.  You can see it at [http://butgod.tv/home2](http://http:butgod.tv/home2).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

$( '.uk-tab, .uk-tab-responsive' ).append( '<li> <a class="linkvid" href="http://www.espn.com">More Videos</a> </li>' );
$('.linkvid').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 window.location.href  = "http://www.espn.com" + this.id;

}); 
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use the native a href ?

Comment: Perhaps the code has been reduced to the necessary parts.

Comment: @Zim84 maybe ... But I see here is that the code overrides the onclick event and the handler in this override just do the same thing as the default behavior

Comment: Floverdevel, it does seem like the onclick event is being overridden.  Is there a way to prioritize the event so that it supersedes all other events? Or disable the conflicting events?  I apologize in advance if my questions seem ignorant.  I’m trying to learn this through trial and error.